# CNV Kit ` from . import commands ImportError: cannot import name 'commands' from '__main__'`

Tags: bash, cnv

I am trying to run some code for my colleague in bash

```
/path/to/cnvkit.py batch /path/to/my/folder/with/bams/*.bam \
  --normal --targets ${bed_file} \
  --fasta path/to/my/resources_broad_hg38_v0_Homo_sapiens_assembly38.fasta \
  --output-reference /path/to/my/CD_BATCH1_reference.cnn \
  --output-dir /path/to/my/Group_1 --scatter
```

however, I keep getting this truly peculiar error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/cnvkit.py", line 4, in <module>
    from . import commands
ImportError: cannot import name 'commands' from '__main__' (/path/to/cnvkit.py)
```

**Attempt 1**

I checked if the path was correct and multiple times I found that it was correct. It did not change the error.

**Attempt 2**

Perhaps I need to `chmod +x *` everything in the CNV kit directory and that will help. It did not change the error.

Why is this error occurring? How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you download it from `conda` and try again? Its here, https://docs.conda.io/en/main/miniconda.html

Then,

```
conda create --name myenv
conda activate myenv
conda install -c bioconda cnvkit
cnvkit batch /path/to/my/folder/with/bams/*.bam --normal --targets ${bed_file} --fasta path/to/my/resources_broad_hg38_v0_Homo_sapiens_assembly38.fasta --output-reference /path/to/my/CD_BATCH1_reference.cnn --output-dir /path/to/my/Group_1 --scatter
```

The path to the file is not used, the command is simply `cnvkit`
This avoids all the privilege stuff and ensures you're running a virtual environment to protect your system Python.

---

To address the comments. "conda" is slow and doesn't ever load.

There is an alternative to conda called **mamba**, this is fast and designed to address this exact issue. I have never needed to use it so the following is a rough guide only.

Download and install via

```
conda create --name myenv
conda activate myenv
conda install -c conda-forge mamba
```

The documentation is here, https://mamba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/mamba.html

I've never used it but the idea is ...

```
mamba create -n mambaenv <list of packages>
mamba activate mambaenv
```

The list of packages could be left blank for now, then,

```
mamba install "Python>=3.10.0" numpy pandas pathlib
mamba install cnvkit # SEE NOTE
```

Can also do

```
mamba install -n mambaenv cnvkit
```

**NOTE** cnvkit exists strictly in -c bioconda. You do not seem to search and install via channels in mamba

You search for a package and its dependencies via

```
mamba repoquery search cnvkit
mamba repoquery depends -a cnvkit
```

It is important to place a virtual environment between the system Python and package Python (don't want a system corruption). More to the question, this would solve all the permission problems without changing your system in anyway (kinda important).

Comment: I did try this before and I tried it again now but for whatever reason I get `Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.` over and over again. It never works though for the command `conda install -c bioconda cnvkit`.

Comment: Okay @Indira thanks. Addressed above

Comment: "I have never needed to use it" you lucky so-and-so! We regular joes need to stick to mamba if we need conda environments solved in one human lifetime.

Comment: @RamRS this is funny. I suggest the reason is that "Regular Joses" (pronounced Hosays) where I am, don't use conda. "Regular Joes" where you are, all use conda. Thus your server always times out. :-)